# Django: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have the following form:

```
class locationForm(forms.Form):

    existing_regions= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Region.objects.none(), label="Region Name", required=False)
    region_name = forms.CharField()
    location_name = forms.CharField()
    street_address = forms.CharField()
    city = forms.CharField()
    zip_code = forms.CharField()
```

And the following update view for this form:

```
class UpdateLocation(View):
    template_name = "dash/location_update_form.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        loc = kwargs['name']

        try:
            location = Location.objects.get(name=loc)
            form = locationForm(instance=location)

            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form,'location': location})

        except (ValueError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
            return redirect(reverse('geofence_manager'))


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        loc = self.kwargs['name']
        try:
            location = Location.objects.get(name=loc)
            form = locationForm (request.POST, instance=location)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
            else:
                form = locationForm(request.POST, instance=location)
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'location': location, 'form': form})

        except (ValueError, ObjextDoesNotExist):
            return redirect(reverse('location_manager'))
        return redirect(reverse('location_manager'))
```

I am receiving an error in regards to 'instance' key word argument being used. I believe this has something to do with me not using a `Modelform`(I could be wrong). But I do not want to use a `Modelform` to construct my form, so is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a model to it?

Comment: I am trying to make an update view that will render the data from an instance it is associated with. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Other than using a `ModelForm`?

Comment: Yes, other than ModelForm..

Comment: Is this a silly question to ask? Because I am getting that impression haha

Comment: This task is exactly what `ModelForm` is designed to do.

Comment: I guess my new question then is, how do I convert this form to a `ModelForm` when it has a `ModelChoiceField` queryset. If you can provide that as the answer I'll go ahead and accept the answer.

Comment: You can use ModelChoiceField in ModelForm based form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class locationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'
```

in your view:

```
...
locationForm.base_fields['existing_regions'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= ...)
form = locationForm()
```

Comment: Hi Simeon,

Can you point to an explanation for why this needs to be in the view instead of in the form definition? I get a KeyError with an exception value of 'manager' when trying to run the queryset in the forms.py file. Your solution here worked for new forms, but if I try to set the initial state of a ModelMultipleChoice field, then the KeyError comes back.